# How to download XML with RestClient?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, rest, restsharp

I have a url that contains valid xml, but unsure on how I could retrieve this with RestClient. I thought I could just download the string and then parse it like I allready to with WebClient.

Doing:

```
        public static Task<String> GetLatestForecast(string url)
        {
            var client = new RestClient(url);
            var request = new RestRequest();

            return client.ExecuteTask<String>(request);
        }
```

Makes VS cry about that 'string' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor.

See executetask:

```
namespace RestSharp
{
    public static class RestSharpEx
    {
        public static Task<T> ExecuteTask<T>(this RestClient client, RestRequest request)
            where T : new()
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>(TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

            client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, (handle, response) =>
            {
                if (response.Data != null)
                    tcs.TrySetResult(response.Data);
                else
                    tcs.TrySetException(response.ErrorException);
            });

            return tcs.Task;
        }
    }
}
```

*Thanks to Claus Jørgensen btw for a awesome tutorial on Live Tiles!*

I just want to download the string as I already have a parser waiting for it to parse it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is a string, just use this approach instead:

```
namespace RestSharp
{
    public static class RestSharpEx
    {
        public static Task<string> ExecuteTask(this RestClient client, RestRequest request)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>(TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);

            client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
            {
                if (response.ErrorException != null)
                    tcs.TrySetException(response.ErrorException);
                else
                    tcs.TrySetResult(response.Content);
            });

            return tcs.Task;
        }
    }
}
```